# I post a form to PHP in java, but no response in Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: java, php, http, post, server

As the title, I want to implement a Web server by Java, the only problem is that I need post a form to login.php and then get the response.
The following code is how I post the data to PHP.

```
URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:6789" + req.uri);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
// Convert string to byte array, as it should be sent
// req.form is the form data to post to the login.php
byte[] postDataBytes = req.form.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

// set the form from request as the post data to PHP
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

// get response
int code = conn.getResponseCode();
InputStream is;
if (code == 200) {
    is = conn.getInputStream();
    fillHeaders(Status._200_);
} else {
    is = conn.getErrorStream();
    fillHeaders(Status._404_);
}

// get response conetent length from login.php
int length = conn.getContentLength();
```

The content of login.php is very simple:

```
<?php
echo 'User name is：' . $_POST['loginName'];
?>
```

When I debug this part, I will stall in this line

```
int code = conn.getResponseCode();
```

That means I cannot get response from login.php

So how can I change the code or the enviornment of ubuntu (maybe the version of php?) to solve this problem.

Thx. XD

Comment: Use `php-cgi` can solve this problem.

Answer (score -1):

If java is the server and PHP is a client you should open listening connection in java.

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8080);
 System.out.println("Listening for connection on port 8080 ....");
 while (true) { 
Socket clientSocket = server.accept();
 InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()); 

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
 String line = reader.readLine();
 while (!line.isEmpty()) { 
System.out.println(line); line = reader.readLine(); 
} 
}
```

Comment: The question clearly describes the request going from java to PHP, not the other way round. Either way, you wouldn't open a raw socket connection to receive a HTTP request...there are much better ways of launching a webserver

Comment: ADyson said right. Thx, but I still hava no solution about this problem.